# How can I retrieve Users of a specific User Group with GraphQL?

Tags: users, graphql

I want all the users but filtered by User Group:

```
query getAllUsers {
  users {
    id,
    username
  }
}
```

I cannot see any query parameter on the Schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible on Craft `3.3.x` but `group` and `groupId` have been added since `3.4.0-beta.5` ([commit](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/commit/1934c38fbdaa78cb105e8ed5b9edb8bcbf4e2800))

With the update, you can do:

```
query getAllUsers{
  users(groupId:1) {
    id,
    username
  }
}
```

Or:

```
query getAllUsers{
  users(group:"groupHandle") {
    id,
    username
  }
}
```